# separar cifra de numero a digitos separados

Tags: c

mi pregunta es acerca de como hago para separar un numero que tengo en un arreglo a digitos separados, estoy trabajando en c

```
numero[4]={14,4,4,8,6};
```

al final quiero que quede 1,4,4,4,8,6

Comment: Hola **Angel Lars** Tienes algún avance en tu código, si lo tienes puedes editar el desarrollo de tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

using namespace std;
//Sirve desde 0 hasta 99
int main () {
   int num[5]={14,4,4,8,6};
   int save[MAX];
   int cont=0;
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      if(num[i]>9){
         save[i]=num[i]/10;
         save[i+1]=num[i]%10;
         cont+=2;
      }
      else{
         save[i]=num[i]%10;
         cont++;
      }
   }
   for(int i=0;i<cont;i++){
      printf("%d ",save[i]);
   }
   return(0);
}
```

Podrías hacer el código más eficiente si utilizas funciones, como por ejemplo hacer un arreglo de mayor dimension, y que pueda particionar numeros mayores a 99.

Comment: ¿Por qué sería el código más eficiente al usar funciones? Y cuando hablas de eficiencia... ¿a qué te refieres exactamente? ¿Mejor uso de la memoria? ¿Tiempo de ejecución? ¿Se reduce el número de instrucciones del programa? ¿se reduce la paginación? ¿Se optimiza el uso de la cache?